# i use getText() in netbeans so it shows deprecation error how to convert getText() to getPassword ()?

Tags: netbeans, jpasswordfield

```
     String sql;
     sql = "select * from login where username = ? and password = ?";
     conn=MySqlConnect.ConnectDB();
     try
     {
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1, txtusername.getText());
        pst.setString(2, txtpassword.getText());
        rs = pst.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next())
        {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Username and Password correct");


enter code here
```

when i tend to change getText() it throws an error while building

Comment: Look at the second answer in the above link.

Comment: I don't understand your comment, this *does* convert the password to a string: `String myPass=String.valueOf(passwordField.getPassword());`. Could you please clarify?

Comment: i just replaced the getText() by getPassword() it throws an error like char[] cannot be converted to strings,Do i need to change the entire coding just to change getText() to getPassword??

Comment: And what is the reason why you don't use the *correct (?)* code I just gave you? :)

Comment: okay let me try it patrick,thanks for your great help :)